# can we know if remote jupyter notebook cell computation is complete?

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I use a remote jupyter notebook through ssh tunneling, Some code sections/cells can take an hour to complete, so I may logoff and reconnect later.

when i reconnect to the notebook, how can I know if the cell has finished its computation before I start executing the following cells?

Comment: Doesn't the currently-running cell have an asterisk by it, rather than the cell number? That is, `[ * ]` instead of, say, `[ 42 ]`. So if the cell doesn't have an asterisk, you can run the next cells.

Comment: no when i log off from the session, the cell in the remote notebook is still running, when I come back to the notebook the next day all i see is a blank [ ]. I dont see if it has completed or not.

Comment: Interesting. As a hack you can run `top` over ssh and see if the notebook's process is consuming CPU. But I'm afraid I don't have a nicer way of doing it within the notebook besides trying to run the next cell (or any cell) and seeing what happens.

Comment: Yes that's how i am currently doing it, using top. But what if I have multiple notebooks... it gets a little messy

Comment: Currently disconnecting doesn't work well. We're planning to have the server track the notebook state, so it will continue to update even if you're not connected. But that requires some significant architectural changes.